# How to initialize all the elements of a 2D array to any specific value in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, initialization, memset

In C++ there are a function ( memset() ) which initialize the values of a 1D array and any multidimensional-array. but in java there are a function fill which initialize the 1D array but can't initialize the multidimensional-array .

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What are you trying to do in java, how are you trying to do it and why it doesn't work?

Comment: Did you try it using two loops?

Comment: I didn't use the loops yet

Comment: if x is a 2D integer arrays then.to fill all the value in x with 3 use `Arrays.stream(x).forEach(a->{Arrays.fill(a,03);}); `

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Arrays.fill()` method can be used to fill a 1-d array, but there's no built in method to do a "deep" fill of multi-dimensional arrays.

For 2-d arrays I do something like this:

```
int[][] arr2 = new int[5][5];  
for(int[] arr1 : arr2) 
  Arrays.fill(arr1, 1);
```

Comment: painful.  Too bad this were not improved in java8/9 timefraem

Answer (score 0):

In Java, we can use Streams to fill in the values of a 2D matrix.

Suppose I want to initialize a 2D Character Array then I will use below:

example1:

```
char[][] temp=new char[5][5];

Arrays.stream(temp).forEach(row->Arrays.fill(row,'.'));
```

example2:

If it's an int array, then.

```
int[][] temp=new int[5][5];

Arrays.stream(temp).forEach(row->Arrays.fill(row,1));
```